# Excel calculation return wrong value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm building a simple POS to calculate item cost. I'm able to calculate item cost for Belts and Scarf but when i calculate item cost for jewellery
it return the wrong calculating.

The formula i'm using `= B37 * VLOOKUP(B36, A2:B5, 2, TRUE)`

[image: Excel Picture]

Comment: like: `=B37*INDEX(B:B,MATCH(B36,A1:A4,0))`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your items aren't sorted. You must sort items (A3:A5)  A to Z.

Changing TRUE to FALSE changes the way VLOOKUP works:

> If TRUE or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an
>   exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than
>   lookup_value is returned.  The values in the first column of
>   table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP
>   may not give the correct value. For more information, see Sort data.
>
> If FALSE, VLOOKUP will only find an exact match. In this case, the
>   values in the first column of table_array do not need to be sorted. If
>   there are two or more values in the first column of table_array that
>   match the lookup_value, the first value found is used. If an exact
>   match is not found, the error value #N/A is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Change the "TRUE" in your formula to "FALSE" and it should work.

```
= B37 * VLOOKUP(B36,A2:B5,2,FALSE)
```